# Finding a basis for a set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U = \{p \in P_4(\mathbb{R}): p''(6) = 0\}$. Find a basis for $U$, then expand that basis to be a basis of $P_4(\mathbb{R})$.

So I've been trying to find examples on how to approach this. I am able to do these types of problems when $U$ is explicitly written as a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ or something along those lines, I'm just having trouble translating the same logic to polynomials and understanding how $p''$ fits into all this.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** A polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4 x^4$ can be reprensented by a vector $[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4]\in\mathbb R^5$. Since $p''(x) = 2a_2 + 6a_3x + 12 a_4 x^2$, the equation $p''(6)=0$ is a linear equation of the type $$k_0a_0 + k_1a_1 + k_2a_2 + k_3a_3 + k_4a_4,$$ you just have to determine the coefficients $k_i$.

Comment: I just don't understand the p double prime part works, could you maybe give an example that isn't this problem on how to find the vector of coefficients if p''(6) = 0?

Comment: @Soaps do you know what derivatives of functions are?

Comment: yeah I understand what they are. So like lets say p = x + x^2 + x^3, then p'= 1+2x+3x^2 and p'' = 0 + 2 + 6x then for p''(6) = 0 in this case, your coefficients would have to be [1, -14, 1] (correct me if I'm wrong I'm kind of tired). What I'm confused about is when working with x^4 polynomials arent there multiple combinations of coefficents that could make p''(6) = 0? How do you determine what they are?

Comment: If you know what a derivative is, then you know what $p''$ is for $p(x) =  a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4 x^4$. Then, simply write down the equation you get when you set $p''(6)$ to $0$.

Comment: So then I can represent the vector in this problem as $[a_1, 2a_2, 36a_3, 24a_4]$??

Comment: No. I will write this again: write down the equation you get when you set $p''(6)=0$.

Comment: That simple? Then if I wanted to expand the basis I get there to be a basis for $P_4$(R) could I just add x^3 and x^4? Also thanks for all your help!

Comment: No, you can't just add $x^3$ and $x^4$, because, for example, $x^4 - 12 x^3$ is already an element of your set $U$.

Comment: @5xum has told you what to do, twice, but you haven't done it, so here it is a third time: WRITE DOWN THE EQUATION YOU GET WHEN YOU SET $p''(6)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

5xum has given you a good general method of solving this kind of problem.  Here is a short cut worth thinking about.

Every polynomial in $P_4$ can be written as
$$p(x)=a+b(x-6)+c(x-6)^2+d(x-6)^3+e(x-6)^4$$
for certain constants $a,b,c,d,e$.  We then have
$$p''(x)=2c+6d(x-6)+12e(x-6)^2$$
and
$$p''(6)=2c\ .$$
Therefore $p\in U$ if and only if $c=0$.  So a basis for $U$ is
$$\{1,\,x-6,\,(x-6)^3,\,(x-6)^4\}$$
and a basis for $P_4$ which includes this is
$$\{1,\,x-6,\,(x-6)^2,\,(x-6)^3,\,(x-6)^4\}\ .$$